# Keys of a dictionary of lists to a row-enumerated, tab-delimited csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, key, enumerate

My dictionaries that include names of characters and their offsets look like this:

```
{'Amestris': [(2247, 2255)],
     'Beda': [(3266, 3270)],
     'Fuery': [(2285, 2290),
               (2380, 2385),
               (2686, 2691),
               (2723, 2728),
     'Gloria': [(1565, 1571)],
     'Hawkeye': [(22, 29),
                 (832, 839),
                 (999, 1006),
                 (1119, 1126),
                 (1927, 1934),
                 (3007, 3014),
                 (4068, 4075)]}
```

My desired output would be the keys of the dictionary (the character names).

In addition, the first column should be enumerating the character names as their Ids, starting from `0`.

The tab-delimited csv file should look like this:

```
Id  Label
0  Amestris
1  Beda
2  Fuery
3  Gloria
4  Hawkeye
```

So far I've reached this point:

```
import csv
import pickle

exmen = pickle.load(open("exmen.p", "rb"))

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    i = 0
    fieldnames = ['Id', 'Label']
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(i(dict(fieldnames, (key))) for key in exmen)
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
line 28, in <module>
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ', fieldnames=fieldnames)

TypeError: 'fieldnames' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I'm not sure how to include the headers `Id` and `Label` other than using `fieldnames` and how to implement the enmuerating of the rows, here I tried to apply `i = 0` and tried to find somewhere in the last line to apply an `i += 1` but it gave me the error warning `syntax error`

Any ideas for improving the code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `csv.DictWriter()` instead of `csv.writer`

Comment: @Rakesh when I do that I get the error: `AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'keys'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fieldnames` is only an argument for `csv.DictWriter` which you do not need here. You could try sth. along the following lines, using `csv.writer`:

```
with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')  # tab delimited
    w.writerow(['Id', 'Label'])        # just write header row
    w.writerows(enumerate(exmen))      # write (id, key) rows
```

If `exmen` is common `dict`, there is no guarantee of the keys' order. You can do:

```
    w.writerows(enumerate(sorted(exmen)))
```

to enforce alphabetical order.

Comment: This works nicely! But the file that I'm getting has empty rows between the actual results. Is there a way to avoid that? PS: VfB ein Leben lang!

Comment: It should not have empty rows. Do you have any other code running? PS: 1893 hey hey!

Comment: Not really, my code in the question above is exactly what my code file has. That's odd...it's like it skips a line and then prints the result every time.

Comment: Ah, I searched for the issue in here a bit and found that adding `newline=''` after `'w'` solves it. Thanks! weiß-rote Grüße aus Stuttgart.

Comment: That is still weird though. Could it be that some of your keys end in `\n`.

Comment: This could be the case, yes; The keys are automatically generated from a pipeline, and sometimes the keys include symbols, spaces etc. The dictionary I posted above is just a sample from one of those dictionaries that looked semi-normal.